Stability of Dynamic spatial panel data model in Stata
I am trying to sum of the coef. of dependent variable lagged in time + dependent variable lagged in both space and time + dependent variable lagged in space (p+n+t) as the below, in order to test whetever this sum smaller than 1, which means the model is stable. I tried to use lincom and testnl command in Stata but it doesn't work in this situation.
How can I test this sum by using Stata?

